# How to properly size and align images?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a table with some cells that have an image on the right side. To make it work on all devices, I used constraints to "tie" the image to the right side and also to center it vertically in the cell, like this:

[image: Set contrstraints]

The image is 512x512 px, the space it should fit in is 75x75 (the whole cell is set to be 95 tall). When I build the project, the images are really big, like this:

[image: Screwed up images]

When I tried to fix it by lowering the images' resolutions to 75x75, they ended up being blurry, as shown here:

[image: Blurry images]

Now I don't know what to do. If I don't use the constraints, the images are fine (nor big nor blurry), but they aren't positioned well in the cell.

Comment: You can pin the width and height if you want the `UIImageView` to be `75x75`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done nothing to constrain the size of the image.  I would suggest:

1. Add an additional constraint which is a vertical offset from the top of the imageView to the top of its superview (the cell content view).  Set the `constant` to `10`. That combined with it being constrained to the vertical center will constrain its height.
2. Add an *Aspect Ratio* constraint to make width and height equal.  To do this, <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag within the imageView and select *Aspect Ratio* from the popup.  Make sure the `multiplier` for this new constraint is set to `1:1`. This will constrain the width to be the same as the height which was established in step 1.
3. For the imageView, in the *Attributes Inspector*, set its content mode to *Aspect Fill* or *Scale to Fill*.

---

This will allow the image to grow if you made your cell taller.  You could add constraints to make the width and height each `75` instead of using the vertical offset and aspect ratio constraints.  You'd still need the *Scale to Fill* mode set though.

Answer (score 0):

Give the constraints `fixed hieght & width` to the image so that it won't resize according to image size.